# Missing GLES 3.0 option for Android Studio AVD

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I try to test an app that has a GLES 3.0 renderer using the Android Studio emulator on my MX Linux O.S (Debian derivative). I selected a Pixel 3 Android 30 virtual device.
The options available for the graphics are limited to GLES 2.0.

[image]

I'm not sure such a device doesn't support GLES 3.0. Any though can be useful.

Comment: I gave up trying to use the emulator for graphics on linux a long time ago. It probably has something to do with X11, Mesa, or Wayland. I filed bug reports with them that never were dealt with. Its less a waste of time to just get the cheapest Android device you can test with...

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be enabled inside the emulator, keep `Emulated Performance` on `Automatic`, then open the emulator and go to:

`...->settings->advanced->OpenGL ES API level->Renderer maximum`

Then restart the emulator

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

What AVD can expose in terms of API support depends on the host machine, so the graphics API support isn't guaranteed to match the actually level of API support in the emulated device. Nothing beats using real hardware here.